# Google Cloud Engine Use Https Load Balancer

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, gke-networking

I'm trying to setup my node.js web service hosted with k8s on google cloud to use https.

When you create a new service in k8s engine then it creates a default http load balancer. I'm trying to make it create a https load balancer instead.

Is there any way that I can change this behavior to be https?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to route HTTPS traffic to a backend, the load balancer must have a certificate so it can prove its identity to your clients. Therefore it is required to have a private key to complete the HTTPS handshake.

To provision a certificate on HTTP(S) load balancer with a certificate and key, you can specify the name of a Kubernetes Secret in the ‘tls’ field of your Ingress manifest. I hope you will find this [help center article](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#setting_up_https_tls_between_client_and_load_balancer) helpful in implementing your concern.